# Count-Syllables function scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to Implement the procedure count-syllables which takes a list of letters as its argument and returns the number of syllables in the word formed by the letters, according to the following rule:

The number of syllables is the number of vowels, except that a group of consecutive vowels counts as one. Vowels are the letters:

```
 (define vowels '(a e i o u))
```

example:

```
       (count-syllables '(s o a r i n g)) ; output = 2 ('oa' and 'i')
        (count-syllables '(b e e p)) ; output = 1 ('ee')
```

I have writen this code :

```
              (define count-syllables
                  (lambda (l)
                      (if (empty? l)
                          0
                       (if (memq (car l) '(a e i o u)) ; if we found a match
                               (+ 1 (count-syllables (cdr l)))
                                      (count-syllables (cdr l))))))
```

but this code doesnt count consecutive vowels as one when typing '(s o a r i n g)
it outputs 3 and when typing '(b e e p) it outputs 2

Answer (score 2):

You need to account for the consecutive vowels instead of adding 1 everytime you find a vowel. Here is an example of how you can handle such a case using mutual recursion:

```
(define (count-syllables lst)
  (cond
    ((null? lst) 0)
    ((member (car lst) '(a e i o u))
     (+ 1 (skip-vowels (cdr lst))))
    (else
     (count-syllables (cdr lst)))))

(define (skip-vowels lst)
  (cond
    ((null? lst)
     (count-syllables '()))
    ((member (car lst) '(a e i o u))
     (skip-vowels (cdr lst)))
    (else
     (count-syllables lst))))
```

Essentially, everytime you find a vowel in the list, you add 1, then send that list to `skip-vowels`, which then removes the next consecutive vowels and sends the list back to `count-syllables`.

Then you can have:

```
(count-syllables '(s o a r i n g))
=> 2
(count-syllables '(b e e p))
=> 1
```

Comment: maybe "skip-vowels" is a better name. I'd expect `(remove-consecutive-vowels "abeeg")` to return `"abg"`. :)

Comment: Hm that's a fair point. Perhaps it will be less misleading if I renamed it to `skip-vowels`. I'll update the post, thanks.